# Pi precision, can it be done ahead of time in a computation?

Tags: number-theory, summation, pi

Consider this question

> Given that Pi can be estimated using the function 4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 -
>   1/7 + …) with more terms giving greater accuracy, write a function
>   that calculates Pi to an accuracy of 5 decimal places.

This is typically a programming question but I wonder if it can be done mathematically, too, since the trick is knowing when to stop computing.

I can write that summation as

$$\pi = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

What does it mean to have something to $d$ digits of precision exactly? If $r$ is the result of our computation, do we say that $|\pi-r| \leq \frac{1}{10^{d+1}}$? Is this right?

If so, can we figure out what upper bound on the summation will get us there?

I think it is the same as asking when $$\left|\pi - \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right| \leq \frac{1}{10^6}$$

and solving for $n$, right?

Comment: This is an alternating series; there are known upper bounds for the partial sum, for instance $|R_n| \leq |a_{n+1}|$, where $R_n$ is the $n$'th remainder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost right.  Usually, "$n$ decimal places" means "less than $5/10^{n+1}.$
Since this is an alternating series, we know the error in using the first $k$ terms is less than the absolute value of the $k+1$st term.  So you need to solve 
$4/(2(k+1)+1) \leq 5/10^6.$

Comment: How do you know this about the absolute error since it's an alternating series?

Comment: It's a standard theorem in every calculus text.  The other error-bounding theorem is the remainder term for Taylor series, and it is usually not as good.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it is an alternating series of terms which are monotonically decreasing in absolute value. Only in this case do you have this error estimate. This constraint being necessary is actually quite obvious when you think about it; consider, say, a sequence which looks like $(-1)^n/n$ except that the $100$th term is $100$ instead of being $1/100$. At any rate, you have this monotonicity in this situation so there is no problem.

Comment: Also, you forgot about the $4$: you actually need $\frac{4}{2k+3} \leq 5 \cdot 10^{-6}$.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that we're on Earth, and that the angular momentum at this latitude can be neglected in this computation.

Comment: That is one of the worst series available for calculating  pi, as  it converges so slowly.